# Criar e remover aquivos no Visual Studio enquanto está "debugando"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Não consigo criar nem remover arquivos enquanto meu projeto .NET está rodando, já tentei ativar/desativar várias opções do Visual Studio mas não encontrei o que está bloqueando esta edição.

Não preciso que o debug "recompile" os arquivos em runtime, preciso somente liberar a opção de criar novos arquivos enquanto a aplicação estiver rodando, como views, css, etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: não consigo criar nem arquivos do tipo "View".

Comment: É exatamente o que não quero fazer... Eu sei que é possível editar ou criar arquivos enquanto a aplicação está rodando pois em outras instalações do Visual Studio 2015 nunca tive este problema, somente neste, rs.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso, só que não é dessa forma no VS2015.
Tente:

1. Execute o projeto, mas *ultrapasse* o modo debug (CTRL + F5). O modo de debug precisa recompilar pra processar os arquivos modificados.
2. Instale o dnx-watch usando esse comando: `dnu commands install Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher`. Você pode ler mais sobre isso [aqui](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8/)(site me inglês).

(fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267588/how-can-i-add-or-rename-files-in-visual-studio-while-the-project-is-running)

Comment: Não é necessário que o debug recompile os novos arquivos em runtime, preciso somente poder criar novos arquivos enquanto a aplicação está sendo executada, como views, css, etc.